# Python class utcnow not updating

Tags: python, class, default-value, python-datetime

I have setup a simple class in Python with a member posted that defaults to `utcnow()` time as a string. However when I create an instance of the class then create another instance a few minutes later they both have the exact same posted time.
If in the route I have created I pass in `posted=str(datetime.utcnow())` it works fine so Python is picking up the computer datetime correctly. I have also tested this on a Heroku app I have running and I get the same problem.
The time it puts in is the time the app was first run as if it's being treated as a static value.

```py
import uuid
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Dict
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from models.model import Model


@dataclass
class Dummy(Model):
    collection: str = field(init=False, default='dummy')
    text: str
    posted: str = field(default=str(datetime.utcnow()))
    _id: str = field(default_factory=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex)

    def json(self) -> Dict:
        return {
            "text": self.text,
            "posted": self.posted,
            "_id": self._id
        }
```

Comment: Why not add and `__init__` to the class and set `posted` therein? That should set the property every time you create an instance of the class. And by the way, note [this](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `default_factory` instead in case you want a dynamically default value.

```py
@dataclass
class Dummy(Model):
    ...
    posted: str = field(default_factory=lambda: str(datetime.utcnow()))
```